# Help with law of sines and cosine tower of piza problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The tower of piza is $56\,\mathrm{m}$ tall including the flagpole. In $1990$ the tower leaned at an angle of $5.5°$ and was considered structurally unsound. The tower was straightened to $4°$ in order to be considered safe. How much did the flagpole move as a result of straightening the tower? Round your answer to the nearest hundredth of a meter.

I am extremely confused, I have tried to draw pictures, but they don't make sense, and I don't know what to do. I do know that I am supposed to use the law of sines and cosines somehow because this is a part of a lab that has revolved around that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to find a base in isosceles triangle with $56 \:m$ legs and vertex angle $1.5°$ (angles difference). The flag pole movement $x=2\cdot 56\cdot\sin 0.75°$ (height is also a bisector and a median in isosceles triangle).